# c++ assign a class member function a lambda function for computation efficiency

Tags: performance, class, c++11, lambda, member-functions

**UPDATED: (Rephrased)**.  I'm looking to boost the computation efficiency of my code by make an run-time assignment of a class member function to one of many functions conditional on other class members.

One recommended solution uses `#include <functional>` and `function<void()>`, as shown in the simple test example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Number {
  int n;
  function(void()) doIt;

  Number(int i):n(i) {};

  void makeFunc() {

      auto _odd  = [this]() { /* op specific to odd */ };
      auto _even = [this]() { /* op specific to even */ };

    // compiles but produces bloated code, not computatinally efficient
      if (n%2) doIt = _odd;   
      else     doIt = _even;  
  };
};

int main() {
  int i;
  cin >> i;
  Number e(i);
  e.makeFunc();
  e.doIt();
};
```

I'm finding that the compiled code (i.e. debug assembly) is grotesquely complicated and presumably NOT computationally efficient (the desired *goal*).

Does someone have an alternative construct that would achieve the end goal of a **computationally efficient** means of conditionally defining, at run-time, a class member function.

Comment: Did you try to replace `void (*doIt)();` with `std::function<void> doIt;`?

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question. This one cannot get any new answers.

Comment: When you're saying it's not efficient, what was the baseline code you were comparing the *performance* against? It's a rhetorical question, I know you didn't. What I'm saying: you should.

Comment: "I'm finding that the compiled code (i.e. debug assembly) is grotesquely complicated and presumably NOT computationally efficient" Don't presume, benchmark. And bloated assembly code does not imply inefficiency; generally quite the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *capturing* lambda expression cannot be assigned to a regular function pointer like you have.

I suggest using

```
std::function<void()> doIt;
```

instead of

```
void (*doIt)();
```

Comment: "cannot be assigned" - An that's because the type of a lambda is not utterable, so you cannot assign it to something which has a type. You need a construct that does type erasure.